# CXF - custom exception is not caught by CXF

Tags: spring, soap, cxf

I am developing a SOAP web service with CXF 2.3.3. I want to throw a custom exception when user has submitted wrong data. My exception class looks like this.

```
@WebFault(name="InvalidUserDataException", targetNamespace="http://foo.bar.com/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class InvalidUserDataException extends RuntimeException {

public InvalidUserDataException(){
    super();
}

    String validationErrors;

}
```

In my method Impl class I purposely throw this exception to see whether SoapFault exception is returned by CXF to client, but whatever I do to any of these classes results in same error: createNewUser has thrown exception, unwinding now.

Note that WSUserRegistration interface also declares itself that createNewUser method throws InvalidUserDataException.

```
public class WSUserRegistrationImpl implements WSUserRegistration {

@Autowired
IWSUserValidationProxy validationProxyImpl;

@Override
public int createNewUser(RegistrationInputProperty registrationInfo) throws InvalidUserDataException {

    if (true) {
        throw new InvalidUserDataException();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

}

My goal is to catch this exception from a SOAPFaultOutInterceptor and return a customized faultDetail.

How do I make CXF catch this error and return a SOAPFault object? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would help you.
http://willemjiang.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-map-soap-fault-message-with.html

Comment: Hello dursun, I am still getting the same error "createNewUser has thrown exception, unwinding now" with no luck. By the way I am a newbie to CXF

Comment: Is there any annotation that I have to put in addition to the above ones?

Comment: Ok. Solved, Even when I had activated interceptors programmatically I had forgotton to add <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus> this fragment to cxf.xml file and CXF didn't log the outgoing SOAPFault exception message making me think that SOAPFault message is not generated by CXF when it encounters an error.