# Custom @Webfaults with CXF and Camel in transacted routes

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, apache-camel

Problem: I am throwing a @Webfault annotated checked exception in a transacted route behind a CxfConsumer but on the client the details tag does not exist and Camel can not map the exception back to my custom type. This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060366/cxf-custom-exception-is-not-caught-by-cxf) previously without the Camel part.

My solution: I found [this old issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3033) which implemented exactly what I was trying to do, so why did it not work? I started digging into the CxfConsumer code and found out that my custom exception is always wrapped in a RuntimeCamelException and thus the inspection for the @Webfault annotation fails. After patching CxfConsumer to inspect the wrapped cause of the RuntimeCamelException everything is working as expected.

Now my questions: I don't want to use a patched version of CxfConsumer so I need to find out if I am doing something wrong or if the CxfConsumer does not handle my use case. Why is my custom exception wrapped in a RuntimeCamelException and can I somehow prevent that or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom exception is a checked exception and the camel route is transacted. Because of this, the custom exception is wrapped in a RuntimeCamelException which in turn rolls back the transaction.

If you have a setup like this, consider subclassing your exceptions from RuntimeExceptions if you can.

Additionally the Camel CxfConsumer should set the RuntimeCamelException's cause as fault if it exists, which it does not as of yet. I created [CAMEL-6526](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6526) to track this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question is "the fault detail is not set." and you it to be set.

This is a standard behavior of Cxf. There is security issues behind this.
In developpement mode, your can disable this behavior by adding some configuration parameters to your endpoint.

For example this spring/bluepring context example enable the details in the exception. Very usefull in developpement.

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="TenantsWS" address="/TenantsWS" implementor="#TenantsBean">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="faultStackTraceEnabled" value="true" />
        <entry key="exceptionMessageCauseEnabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
<bean id="TenantsBean" class="com.myfundation.services.WsTenants"/>
```

As you can see I just add some jaxws:properties to a 'standard' endpoint configuration.

For the second part of your question, why your exception is wrapped in a RuntimeCamelException... I don't know. But my personalized exceptions are always
annotate with something like :  WebFault(name = "MyException"). I pretty sure everything you search is in the jaxws:properties.

cxf -> 2.7.5

Comment: Setting "exceptionMessageCauseEnabled" had no effect however "faultStackTraceEnabled" works unfortunately I don't need a stacktrace.
This is probably the way to go if you don't have Camel wrapped around CXF.

Comment: so I don't understand the question, sorry.

Comment: Do you already have look at http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html for the management of exception in camel ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am using.
The problem is related to transactional routes, I added an answer.